# Storing a proc inside an array inside a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, proc

I am still working on my text adventure. I am having trouble with the use/with function. It is meant to call a Hash in which the key is the used object and the content includes an array; the first element in the array is the target object, and the second a Proc that will be executed if that relation turns to match the arguments for the use/with function.

Please, may you clarify me **how I can store a code block inside an array inside a hash** so I can recall it later depending on the objects that are being combined?

Here is my use function that takes "use **object** with **with**":

```
    def use(object, with)
    if INTERACTIONS[object][0] == with
        INTERACTIONS[object][1]
    end
end
```

And this is how I defined the relations (so far there is just one):

```
INTERACTIONS = {"key" => ["clock", p = Proc.new{puts "You open the clock!"}]}
```

Whenever I type

```
use key with clock
```

it returns nothing but a new prompt line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `.call` the proc:

```
INTERACTIONS = {"key" => ["clock", Proc.new {puts "You open the clock!"}]}

def use(object, with)
  if INTERACTIONS[object][0] == with
    INTERACTIONS[object][1].call  # procs need to be `call`ed :)
  end
end


use("key", "clock") # => You open the clock!
```