# using proc instead of block inside hash iterator

Tags: ruby, iterator, block, proc

I wrote my own iterator for the class that I'm working on which extends `hash`.

The iterator that I wrote was achieved using blocks and now im trying to achieve the same exact thing using `Proc`. but I kinda don't know how to use it in this context! :(

```
def each_word
   rank=0
   self.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse.to_h.keys.each{ |key,abs, rel | yield rank+=1, 
   key,self[key], self.frequency(key) if block_given? }#iterate with aid block
end
```

and i would use it like this :

```
puts "Rang - Anzahl - Häufigkeit(%) - Wort"
obj1.each_word do |rank,word,abs ,rel|
  puts "#{rank}         #{abs}       #{rel}%        #{word} "
end
```

## using Proc(not correct code)

problem is that i want to have the same code using `Proc`

```
def each_letter
  rank=0
  x=self.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse.to_h# this wont work but wrote it as helpless try
  my_proc=Proc new { |key,abs, rel | yield rank+=1, key,x[key], x.frequency(key) }
  my_proc.call()
end
```

I already looked up those pages

- [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053112/storing-a-proc-inside-an-array-inside-a-hash)
- [external web page 1](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/#Lambdas_vs_Procs)
- [external web page 2](https://mixandgo.com/learn/mastering-ruby-blocks-in-less-than-5-minutes)
- [external web page 3](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/09/04/ruby-magic-closures-in-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas.html)

so what is the correct way to use the provided block using letters?!

## Edit the Assignment text:

> `each_word` iterate over the words found using the method and a block, starting with the most common word to the least common word. The block gets the word, the absolute and relative frequency passed.(which I assume I did correctly)
>
> The letter statics `each_letter` It behaves similarly to `each_word`, but 
>    within the method, you should use a `Proc` instead of a `block`.

Comment: _"trying to achieve the same exact thing using Proc"_ – a proc is not a replacement for `yield` – those are very different things. Why do you want to use a proc in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve by using a proc?

Comment: I see. What does the assignment ask for, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your doing here in your attempt is *wrapping* yield with a Proc, but in reality you can *replace* yield with the Proc:

```
def each_word(&proc)
   rank=0
   keys = self.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse.to_h.keys
   keys.each do |key, abs, rel|
     if proc
       proc.call(rank+=1, key,self[key], self.frequency(key))
     end
   end
end
```

What `&proc` does it take the *block* that is passed in (whether with `do ... end` or `{ ... }` syntax) and *converts* it to a proc.

To check whether a block was given, you would simply use `if proc` (whereas if you were using yield, you'd use `block_given?`). You could alternatively use `proc&.call` which is the [safe navigation operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator).

By the way, you should probably change `rank +=1` to `rank + 1`, there's no no point reassigning the variable's value here since it's not going to change the value in the hash anyway (numbers are immutable).

Comment: thanks a lot man that was so helpful and providing the safe navigation operator reference made me get more info about the usage of the proc :) 
+1